# Clarity on init with `Self` requirement of SectionModelType in RxDataSources

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rxdatasources

Binding a sectioned table with [RxDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources) using a [TableViewSectionedDataSource](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources/blob/master/Sources/RxDataSources/TableViewSectionedDataSource.swift), requires sections which conform to [SectionModelType](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources/blob/master/Sources/Differentiator/SectionModelType.swift).

This [SectionModelType](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources/blob/master/Sources/Differentiator/SectionModelType.swift) protocol has the following initializer as one of it's requirements:

```
    init(original: Self, items: [Item])
```

In addition, the same protocol enforces `var items: [Item] { get }`. We can now initialize the items array backing variable (in above mentioned `init`) with either from `original.items`, or `items` passed as init parameter. This is very confusing. The SectionModelType code has no comments.

[How](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources#how) section of README which explains creation of sections for this very case, talks about creating typealias (for associated value), and the items array, but not a word about following implementation of `init` with `original: Self` :

```
init(original: SectionOfCustomData, items: [Item]) {
    self = original
    self.items = items
}
```

While this can work in a struct, doing the same in a class shouts:

> Cannot assign to value: 'self' is immutable

Can anyone here explain what is happening here and why do we NEED to init with `Self`

Lastly, is there another (cleaner) way to reactively (in RXSwift / RxCocoa only) bind a sectioned table view to an observable datasource. 
e.g. 
* my cells, and sections have their own data model, which need to be mutable (hence classes)
* there are multiple screens with this requirement for different entities, so i would be interesetd in achieving this with protocols instead, and slap the corresponding data model with the protocol ans have a common implementation for RXBinding

Any pointers to either get clarity more on existing implementation, or achieving above points would be really helpful.
P.S.: I am already working in a huge code base which uses Rx, so not using Rx, or moving to SwiftUI etc is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init(original:items:)` is a *copy* initializer. It takes an already existing instance of the struct and makes a new one that is identical except that it changes what's in the `items` property.

So in a protocol declaration, `init(original: Self, items: [Item])` means: "You hand me an already existing instance of whatever this type is that is conforming to me, the protocol, and we'll make a new instance that copies it while changing its `items`."

And that is exactly what the example does. It's easier to see if you put it all together, like this:

```
protocol SectionModelType {
    associatedtype Item
    var items: [Item] { get }
    init(original: Self, items: [Item])
}
struct CustomData {
    var anInt: Int
    var aString: String
    var aCGPoint: CGPoint
}
struct SectionOfCustomData {
    var header: String
    var items: [Item]
}
extension SectionOfCustomData: SectionModelType {
    typealias Item = CustomData
    init(original: SectionOfCustomData, items: [Item]) {
        self = original
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

It's up to you, in your implementation of the extension, to do what they did: set `self` to `original`, which is some already existing SectionOfCustomData object (that is permitted in a struct initializer) and then change its `items`. And you *must* do things like that, and in that order, because if you don't, you'd be trying to initialize a SectionOfCustomData object without setting its `header` property — whereas, this way, we are guaranteed that there is *already* a `header` property value, because we are starting with an already existing SectionOfCustomData object, and you can't make one *without* setting its `header` property.

As for your other worry, that that won't compile if this is a class, not a struct: yes, you're perfectly right, but don't do that. It isn't what they said to do. They said make this a struct, and they meant it.